# Derived class defines function via base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Consider the following code:

```
struct A
{
  virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct B
{
  void f();
};

struct C : public A, public B
{};

int main()
{
  A* a = new C();
  B* b = new C();
  C* c = new C();

  // All these calls should result in B::f
  a->f();
  b->f();
  c->f();
}
```

The compiler states that `C` is abstract.
How can this situation be resolved?
The issue seems similar to diamond inheritance, but I fail to see the solution.

EDIT: Thanks, this is the working example:

```
#include "stdio.h"

struct A
{
  virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct B
{
  void f()
  {
      printf("B::f\n");
  }
};

struct C : public A, public B
{
  void f()
  {
      printf("C::f\n");
      B::f();
  }
};

int main()
{
  A* a = new C();
  B* b = new C();
  C* c = new C();

  printf("Calling from A\n");
  a->f();
  printf("Calling from B\n");
  b->f();
  printf("Calling from C\n");
  c->f();
}
```

Output:

```
Calling from A
C::f
B::f
Calling from B
B::f
Calling from C
C::f
B::f
```

Comment: Just to understand your intent: You want `A` to define an interface, `B` define an implementation and `C` putting them together? I don't see the advantage of this over `B : A`, since when implementing `B`, you already know the interface you are implementing, right?

Comment: I cant simply let `B` derive from `A`, since this is only an isolated example of a problem I encountered in a much bigger project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the two `f()` functions are completely unrelated, even though they happen to have the same name.

If the desired behaviour is for the `C`'s `virtual` `f()` to call `B::f()`, you have to do it explicitly:

```
struct C : public A, public B
{
  void f();
};

void C::f() {
  B::f();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the virtual function from the base class in `C`. If you want it to call `B::f`, say it like this:

```
struct C : A, B
{
    void f() { B::f(); }
};
```